# Php random numbers inside foreach

Tags: php, sql, database, random

I got this:

```
foreach($users as $user) {

    $num = mt_rand(1, 52);

    ...
}
```

this loops through the users in my database and randoms a number between 1 and 52 for each user.

Later it update the db and writes in the randomed number.

Is it possible to give a user a unique number, so that one user does not get the same number as another?

Comment: Make a column (for example user_id) `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a list of the possible numbers and shuffle it; then allocate each of those numbers in turn.... like shuffling and dealing a deck of cards

```
$numbers = range(1,52);
shuffle($numbers);

foreach($users as $user) {
    $num = array_pop($numbers);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try [PHP uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function with timestamp as the paramter.

Comment: "**Warning:** 
This function **does not create random nor unpredictable strings**.  This function **must not be used for security purposes**. Use a cryptographically secure random function/generator and cryptographically secure hash functions to create unpredictable secure IDs."